# Calling two methods from one controller in nested model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, nested-forms

Through other posts on SO I've learned that my sign-up process using a nested model form is flawed in that I create a new `User`, then redirect to create its `Profile`. Here is the process:

```
user = User.new
user.email = ...
user.password = ...
user.profile = Profile.new
user.profile.first_name = ...
...
user.profile.save
user.save
```

It seems as if one solution is to initiate the profile method from within the `UsersController` create(?) action, so that I POST to both models(?) then redirect to a page with a form to fill out the rest of the profile.

But I'm not entirely sure how to do that, as I am new to programming/Rails. So can anyone give me guidance on how to introduce the `Profile` method within the `UsersController`? I gave it a go but don't think it's correct. Code for both Users/ProfilesController below:

**User:**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.profile = Profile.new
end

def index
  @user = User.all
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.profile.save
    redirect_to profile_new_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

**Profile:**

```
def new
  @user.profile = Profile.new
end

def create
  @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
  if @profile.save
    redirect_to profile_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb:**

```
match '/signup' => 'profiles#new', :as => "signup"
get "signup" => "profiles#new", :as => "signup"
root :to => 'users#new'
resources :users
resources :profiles
```

**My nested model form (the relevant parts):**

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => { :action => :create }, :html => {:id => 'homepage'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :size=> 13, :id => "user[email]" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |f| %>
  <% end%>
<% end %>
```

If anyone could help me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this in your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

...of course all backed up with proper migrations. Then while building up a form you can use `fields_for` helper. Here is slightly modified example from docs:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>
  Email: <%= user_form.text_field :email %>
    <%= user_form.fields_for :profile do |profile_fields| %>
      First Name: <%= profile_fields.text_field :first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And update your user and his profile in the controller in one go, thanks to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile` declaration in your model.

Comment: Shouldn't it be :user instead of @user for the nested model form? Doing it that way takes all of the profile fields out. Unless I've got another issue, which could definitely be the case.